# Have Parent Class Use Child Class Logger Name

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to set up some logging and I'm running into a problem. Whenever a child class uses a parent class function, the parent class function logger name is used instead of the child class's logger name.

Let's say I have the following two classes:

Parent Class:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('ParentClass')

class ParentClass:
    def __init___(self):
        logger.info('This is inside ParentClass')
```

Child Class:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('ChildClass')

class ChildClass(ParentClass):
    def foo(self):
        logger.info('This is inside ChildClass')
```

Then I run the following script:

```
import logging
import ParentClass
import ChildClass

# Pretend I set up logging to "example.log"
foo1 = ParentClass.ParentClass()
foo2 = ChildClass.ChildClass()
foo2.foo()
```

My Log file ends up looking like:

```
INFO:ParentClass:This is inside ParentClass  #(<-- this comes from foo1 init)
INFO:ParentClass:This is inside ParentClass  #(<-- this comes from foo2 init)
INFO:ChildClass:This is inside ChildClass    #(<-- this comes from foo2 foo)
```

What I'm looking for is the __init__ call for ChildClass to log under the ChildClass logger like this:

```
INFO:ParentClass:This is inside ParentClass  #(<-- this comes from foo1 init)
INFO:ChildClass:This is inside ParentClass   #(<-- this comes from foo2 init)
INFO:ChildClass:This is inside ChildClass    #(<-- this comes from foo2 foo)
```

Is there anyway to do this without passing the name of the logger I want to use to the ParentClass?

Comment: So I have to set up \__init__ in the child class and then explicitly call it like that? __edit__ That approach does not work and I still end up with the same output in the log file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each of your classes is using its own logger for its own code because you're accessing the logger via a global variable in each of your two modules. If you want the logger tied to the classes instead of the modules, try making it a class variable, and accessing it via `self`:

```
class ParentClass:
    logger = logging.getLogger('ParentClass') # class variable
    def __init___(self):
        self.logger.info('This is inside ParentClass')

class ChildClass(ParentClass):
    logger = logging.getLogger('ChildClass') # override parent class variable
    def foo(self):
        self.logger.info('This is inside ChildClass')
```

Comment: Also, I appreciate you explaining the answer as well!

Answer (score 7):

Building on sureshvv's post, I find it helpful to put this in the `__init__` method of my parent class:

```
self.log = logging.getLogger(self.__class__.__name__)
```

Then, child classes can log using `self.log` and have the `%(name)s` token in the log's format correctly display the child class name, instead of the parent's class name (which is what occurs if you pass `__name__` to `getLogger()`.)

Comment: This is better approach, reduces some boilerplate code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make `logger` an attribute of the classes. As things now stand, `ParentClass` can *only* call the logger defined in its module: it has no access to the logger in the `ChildClass` (unless the ParentClass module imports ChildClass and calls `ChildClass.logger` explicitly).

Instead, do this for the ParentClass module:

```
import logging

class ParentClass:
    logger = logging.getLogger('ParentClass')

    def __init___(self):
        self.logger.info('This is inside ParentClass')
```

and this for ChildClass:

```
import logging
import ParentClass    # I assume you do this, too

class ChildClass(ParentClass):
    logger = logging.getLogger('ChildClass')

    def foo(self):
        self.logger.info('This is inside ChildClass')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can:

```
use self.__class__ as argument to getLogger().
```